# Pyramid: CSRF is getting checked somewhere, but I can't find it

Tags: python, pyramid, csrf

I'm trying to troubleshoot this 403 error that I'm getting:

```
403 Forbidden

Access was denied to this resource.

CSRF token is missing or invalid
```

And I've got my function stripped down to bare metal:

```
@view_config(permission='public', route_name='passwordrecovery', renderer='templates/password-recovery.pt')
def password_recovery(request):
    print('****************************************here')

    if 'email' in request.POST:
        print('****************************************here2')
        print(request.POST.csrf_token)
    else:
        logged_in = authenticated_userid(request)
        form = render('templates/password-recovery.pt', {'logged_in': logged_in}, request)

        return {
            'logged_in': logged_in,
            'form': form,
        }
```

and the form:

```
<div id="login_form" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <form id="passwordrecovery" action="/password-recovery" method="post">
    <h2>Log In</h2>
    <fieldset>
        <input name="csrf_token" type="hidden"
            value="89418871070a0bed0e715ce79f4f2d3a0a149657">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" />
        <br />
        []
        <input type="submit" class="login" name="submit" value="Reset" />
    </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

As you can see, I've got some debug prints in there. What's driving me crazy is that when I load the form I get the '****************************************here
' debug on the console, but after I submit the form, I get an immediate 403.  I don't get another '****************************************here
', nor do I get anything else printing out.

I currently don't have any CSRF checking code anywhere, so I can't fathom where it's being checked. Does Pyramid have an automatic CSRF checker that I'm not aware of?

/EDIT I've discovered that this error only happens when the token is called 'csrf_token'.  Call it anything else and everything works as predicted.

Comment: Do you have any middleware enabled anywhere?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I seriously doubt it, but just to make sure I loaded the test site up on my phone and got the same error when I submitted the form.

Comment: I meant in your WSGI stack; not in your browser. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I really don't know. I'm just testing at the moment, so I'm using the pserve functionality of pyramid. Should be pretty plain-vanilla

Answer (score 0):

Well, for what it's worth, I got it to work, but I'm not sure why.

If I changed the name of the token to '_csrf' instead of 'csrf_token', then it stopped doing the automatic checks.

I suspect that the automatic checks were coming from a new feature in pyramid 1.5: [csrf checking with view predicates](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.5-branch/narr/sessions.html#checking-csrf-tokens-manually)

I also found that if I put 'csrf_check=False' into my decorator, it worked. Strangely, any other value for csrf_check threw a predicate mismatch error.